# Derived Heap Only Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, heap-memory, virtual, destructor

So, I was reading an article from this link about heap-only classes:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Requiring_or_Prohibiting_Heap-based_Objects

I wanted to create a base class that was Heap-Only destroyed by a non-virtual member function:

Destroy() { delete this; }

I created a protected virtual destructor for the class and two protected constructors as well as the destroy function, but I want to ensure that all inherited members can only be destroyed from the Destroy() function as well. I would like if at all possible for them to be able to implement there own destructor additions too.

Any help?

EDIT: PROBLEM:

So, I am dealing with delta compression (and eventually relevancy checks) over a network and trying to find a very maintainable/optimal solution to the problem. I read a bunch about how unreal, Quake, TRIBE and others solve the problem. I wanted to track diffs between my code.

One way I thought of with minimal changes is to create my classes structured as a tree of nodes. Then when something changes it marks its heritage in the tree so you can find the diff very easily for any node on the tree.

While writing this, I found that tracking diffs and new nodes this way is easy, but removed nodes across a network is a bit weird. So, I mark a set of nodes as "deleted" as well for one frame so this diff can be sent over the network.; Then in the clean/reset phase, my classes deleted nodes automatically destroy/clean themselves up.

Comment: I cannot think of anytime in my career that I needed to use `delete this`. It is a bad idea and has red flashing lights all over it.

Comment: Well, they specifically mention as a valid possibility on a few different sites. I believe it is used for objects that somewhat "manage" their own memory (IE a shared pointer implementation), but I am curious how to do it anyway. I could explain what I am using it for in the comments if you'd like...

Comment: 1. Shared pointer does not require this. 2. Please do. Attach it to the end of the question

Comment: I will. I'm not saying this is required, it just seems like a convenient way to do a few things.

Comment: I'm astonished that that is legal. I'd feel better if destroy was static, taking a pointer to the object to destroy. But then that amounts probably to the same machine code...

Comment: I was surprised as well, but some people talked about heap only classes and how this was an easy way to do things if you were careful.

Comment: I see nothing  in your problem description that woud require a heap-only class (which is the only justification for the pattern you described). That objects clean themselves up when done is the eessence of any destructor or, more conveniently, smart pointer.

Comment: ...A destructor and a smart pointer require a work from the outside that I'm eliminating from the need. This will clean up my code by making the clean up internal to the class. I'm not really here to argue about this, but my destroy is actually a markAsCleaned() function which will be called either way.

Comment: The clean function will be called after a send and if the diff just sent contains a "deleted" object that object will clean itself up and disconnect from the tree otherwise it will mark changed nodes as unchanged again. Plain and simple. My exterior code knows nothing and doesn't worry about deletes, memory leaks or smart pointers.

Comment: I did not mean to argue either, except about language constructs and design patterns ;-)..I still fail to see why you want to prevent nodes from being on the stack. Enforcing heap-only allocation is the only reason to have a protected delete function. In fact, this does not relieve your code from knowing about node destruction but actually *forces* it to think about it (in the disguise of destroy) because it cannot any longer happen automagically (through stack or smart pointers).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72619/discussion-between-user3812869-and-peter-schneider).